# JavaFX isn't repositioning (on-resize) properly

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm quite new to JavaFX.. I tried making a simple GUI but it didn't turn out right.

**Here's how it looks in SceneBuilder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qPqW.jpg

[image]
and here in the actual app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttDZi.jpg**
[image]

If I resize it smaller the button will just disappear.. If I resize it bigger it would be fine.
Sorry if I didn't explain this well..

---

### Main.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

### Controller.java

```java
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {
    @FXML private Button logoutButton;
    @FXML private AnchorPane scene;
    Stage stage;

    public void logout() {
        stage = (Stage) scene.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

---

### sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="scene" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="500.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="logoutButton" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" text="Logout" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I added the code to the question but I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you :) Good starter, but how does it demonstrate the difference between its actual behaviour and what you expect? What onResize do you mean?

Comment: btw: don't hard-code sizes when the layout isn't as you expect it to be - here a probable culprit is that sizing the scene/stage conflicts with the hard-coded sizes in the fxml

Comment: I don't get it.... @kleopatra

Comment: You should remove the `AnchorPane` and use a container that will keep the node in the Center(when you set the Alignment to Center) instead of hardcoding size values if your going to be resizing a lot such as a `VBox` or `HBox` or `BorderPane` to give you some examples

Comment: this really isn't helping....

Comment: You basically need to learn how to use the Parent nodes. The only thing you should have in this case is a `StackPane` as the root node with a `Button` as its child. Start here -> https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are specifying a fixed position for the button (`layoutX="224.0" layoutY="138.0"`). So clearly it won't reposition when the window is resized.

Comment: _I don't get it_ and _this really isn't helping_ indicate that it's time to work through a tutorial on fx layout :)

Comment: this works but it doesn't let me move the button from the center :| @Sedrick

Comment: See my previous post about doing tutorials about parent nodes. That way, you will know what you need to get things laid out the way you want them.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what many of the comments were mentioning, notice in your SceneBuilder image on the bottom left you have a GridPane, and in that GridPane (in one of the cells) you put an AnchorPane. I assume your button lies on the AnchorPane.

AnchorPanes follow a ruling where its children (the button) are assigned exact pixel coordinates, hence, if that pixel is out of view, (the pane is too small) the button will not be visible. This is not what you want. In order to get around this, a new container should be used (as commenters suggested).

I suggest you delete your GridPane (thus everything) to rather drag an drop a BorderPane in the place of where your GridPane was. You will notice that the BorderPane has a center area (as well as top, left, bottom, and right areas)

Place your button in this center area, and try running again. As the BorderPane resizes, the button should move to fit the same relative position.

Comment: it works but I can't position it in the middle... or anywhere I want it...

Comment: okay, how about in the center of your BorderPane, you drag and drop a VBox. Click on the VBox and go to the layout tab, there should be a "HGrow" field which is set to "Inherit". Change that to "Always".

Next, drop a "region" in the VBox, go to the layout tab of the region, and change its "VGrow" attribute to "always" as well. Now, drop your button in the VBox. Finally, right click on the region, and press "Duplicate".

This should should keep your button always in the center.